# Why Breakpoints crash in Latest Visual Studio with latest Node.js?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio

With latest Visual Studio and Node.js 8.4 I get this error when I try to put a break-point in the Node.js app. Any ideas how to get around it?

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

[node-debug2] Error processing "setBreakpoints": Error: Set breakpoints request timed out
    at Timeout.setTimeout (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\NodeAdapter\222e9311\node_modules\vscode-chrome-debug-core\out\src\utils.js:55:24)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:232:11)

### at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:202:5)

### OK

Comment: this appears to be a bug report, not a user programming issue.  make sure you check or add it to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com where VS tracks its issues

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a bug report for visual studio